# Loading data from web causing error

Tags: java, android

In my app, I fire an `onItemClick(..)` listner when a list view item is clicked. In that event, I load data from a webpage using the following code :-

```
try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.spartanjava.com");
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
        String result = "";
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
              response.getEntity().getContent()
            )
          );
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
          result += line + "\n";
        }
} catch (Exception e) {
    tv.setText("Error : "+e.getMessage());//tv is a textview
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have included the following jars in the classpath :-

```
commons-codec-1.6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
httpclient-4.3.3.jar
httpclient-cache-4.3.3.jar
httpcore-4.3.2.jar
httpmime-4.3.3.jar
```

I have the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in my `AnroidManifext.xml` file. The output which I receive is all that is in the `catch-block`. The textview is set with the value `"Error : null"` and the toast is fired. Any idea on how should I proceed?

Comment: Could you share with us the full stack trace ?

Comment: try to print exception not just message as tv.setText("Error : "+e);

Comment: @GiruBhai, wait I am trying that too

Comment: I am getting this error -> `Error : android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Comment: @devaldcool And also you are trying to do network call in main thred,so do it in background.See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: @GiruBhai, ok...do you think that this will solve the problem? Let me try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Exception actually tells you exactly what you are doing wrong. You are not using another thread to perform `NetworkOperations`.

Your code that connects to the url should be executed inside an **AsyncTasks doInBackground()** method, off the **UI-Thread**.

For more info see [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `response.getEntity()` returns null.

As you try to get a InputStream on the entity, through `getContent()`, without checking if the entity is null, it could trigger a NullPointerException.

**EDIT**

NetworkOnMainThreadException is thrown, you have to do network operation in a thread, like in this example : [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception/6343299#6343299)